# In-App purchase failed during beta testing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-play, google-play-services

I am a beginner in developing android app Now i developed one application and added one feature as an In-app purchase Now i uploaded my app in google developer console for beta testing while testing the In-app purchase is not working it shows error  message like this

```
The item you requested is not available for purchase
```

should i enable any permission during uploading of my application?.As a beginner i don't know how to test In-app purchase tell me the write way to check it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You do need the permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
`, but not sure if that's what your error is referring to. Are you sure the item you're trying to purchase is actually in an **Active** state? Please make sure it is. You may also want to check that you're using the correct certificates. It needs to be the same as what's been published on the Play Store. If you're installing through the Play Store's Beta channel though, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: yes i have given the permission.app is in active state.Now its asking me to pay for In-app while i logged in  as a tester

Comment: If you're using your publisher account, make sure you add that as a tester too (it's not enabled as a tester by default). I believe even as a tester, you still need to have a valid payment method to use, however, the payment method won't be charged.

Comment: Thank you Andy yesterday.It works for me